# Having troubles with my math in the program

Tags: c#, linq, math

When I am programming my forum, I am having troubles in differentiating the two digits of information on my csv file.

**The issue is:** If, there are 2 adults who are wanting to go to a place the price = less
However is it is a single adult the price will equal more.

**PROBLEM:** The problem that occurs is that ALL my segments think all Adults should get charged less, when some of the transaction charges should show more.

**To be precise in information:** The File that contains the HolidayTran.CSV has the array[3] that has the information of 1 or 2 adults in the party.

When I carry the function ref double adult is that I am carrying to the top.

**Edited** - This is the **method** that my professor at my university wants...yes slow and stupid, but its his practice final, so I am trying to figure out what I am missing.
**Yes** I understand i am suppose to do my own work, but I hope someone can tell me where my math is wrong in the programming.

**Edited # 2** Changed the Variables to help make it clearer. I found the isolated problem, located at the If loop section, of my equation. It has been multiplying everything by two digits instead of 1. How can I create a function where if the message reads either a 1 or a 2, then the proper math would apply?

**AdultPricing** This function is suppose to choose the proper math, but I tend to lose concept of how to finish off the function proper. If you look at the If loop, you can see where I go wrong...Any Ideas guys?

I am trying to do a if statement bool function, but that is currently not working...I don't know what else is needed atm..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] myfile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\customerinfo.csv");
        var myquery = from mylines in myfile
                      let myfield = mylines.Split(',')
                      let names = myfield[1]
                      let lastname = myfield[2]
                      let id = myfield[0]
                      orderby lastname, names
                      select new { id, names, lastname };
        foreach (var listing in myquery) { cmbcustomerinfo.Items.Add(listing.id + " " + listing.names + " " + listing.lastname); }
    }

    private void cmbcustomerinfo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //recalling all private void information at the top of the combobox file, inorder to send information to the listbox.
        string tempvariable = "";
        string iddvariable = "";
        string format1 = "{0,55}{1,5}";
        string format2 = "{0,-5:d}{1,15:d}{2,20:c}{3,20:c}";
        string format3 = "{0,-15}{1,35:c}{2,20:c}";
        string format4 = "{0,-15}{1,72:c}";
        getCustomerIDFirstName(out tempvariable, out iddvariable);
        getcustomerinfo(iddvariable);


        //set the required information to connect to the Holiday Transaction. Where we can connect if the ID found in Holiday Matchs the ID in CustomerInfo.CSV,
        //then we can show the data of the dates and pricing of the information
        string[] transaction = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\HolidayTrans.csv");
        var TransactionQuery = from myLinesshown in transaction
                               let myfield2 = myLinesshown.Split(',')
                               let customerid = myfield2[0]
                               let datestart = myfield2[1]
                               let numofadults = byte.Parse(myfield2[2])
                               let numofkids = byte.Parse(myfield2[3])
                               where customerid == iddvariable
                               orderby datestart, customerid
                               select new
                               {
                                   customerid,
                                   datestart,
                                   numofadults,
                                   numofkids
                               };





        foreach (var staff1 in TransactionQuery)
        {

            lstInvoice.Items.Clear();
            lstInvoice.Items.Add("Purchase Date     EndDate       Adult Price   Kid Price");

            //set up all variables used or to be used.
            string idgiven = "";
            double KidsSubPricing = 0;
            double AdultPricing = 0;
            double singleddigit = 0;
            double TwinAdultPricing = 0;
            double totaladult = 0;
            double subtotal = 0;
            double subtotal1 = 0;
            double kidpricing = 3300;
            byte NumberOfDaysSpent = 0;
            string EndofDays = "";
            DateTime daybegin;
            DateTime startthedate;
            DateTime datebeginning = DateTime.Now;

            //set the basic functionality to find the proper ID and date to be shown that corresponses to the person. 
            foreach (var transactionfound in TransactionQuery)
            {
                idgiven = transactionfound.customerid;
                datebeginning = DateTime.Parse(transactionfound.datestart); 
                break;
            }
            //set the datetime interval to show the proper grouping later on
           int xyy = datebeginning.Year; 

            //This is suppose to show where and how I can seperate the transaction of single and double pricing. 
            foreach (var transactionfound in TransactionQuery)
            {
                   if (transactionfound.numofadults.ToString().Contains("1"))
                    {
                        singleddigit = transactionfound.numofadults;

                    }
                   if (transactionfound.numofadults.ToString().Contains("2"))
                    {
                        TwinAdultPricing = transactionfound.numofadults;

                    }
                if (transactionfound.customerid == idgiven && DateTime.Parse(transactionfound.datestart).Year == xyy)
                {

                    getpackagepriceinfo(transactionfound.datestart,ref singleddigit, ref TwinAdultPricing,  ref NumberOfDaysSpent);
                    KidsSubPricing = transactionfound.numofkids * kidpricing;
                    //AdultPricing = transactionfound.numofadults * TwinAdultPricing;
                    subtotal += KidsSubPricing;
                    subtotal1 += AdultPricing;
                    daybegin = DateTime.Parse(transactionfound.datestart);
                    startthedate = daybegin.AddDays(NumberOfDaysSpent);
                    EndofDays = startthedate.ToString("d");
                    lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format2, daybegin, EndofDays, AdultPricing, KidsSubPricing));

                }
                else
                {
                    lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format3, "Subtotal Amount",subtotal1, subtotal));
                    lstInvoice.Items.Add(" ");
                    getpackagepriceinfo(transactionfound.datestart,ref singleddigit,  ref TwinAdultPricing, ref NumberOfDaysSpent);
                    KidsSubPricing = transactionfound.numofkids * kidpricing;
                    //AdultPricing = transactionfound.numofadults * singleddigit;
                    subtotal += KidsSubPricing;
                    subtotal1 += AdultPricing;
                    daybegin = DateTime.Parse(transactionfound.datestart);
                    startthedate = daybegin.AddDays(NumberOfDaysSpent);
                    EndofDays = startthedate.ToString("d");
                    lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format2, daybegin, EndofDays, AdultPricing, KidsSubPricing));
                    idgiven = transactionfound.customerid;
                    xyy = DateTime.Parse(transactionfound.datestart).Year;
                }
                if (idgiven == "")
                {
                    lstInvoice.Items.Clear();
                    lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format1, "Sorry no Transaction Found For" + " ", tempvariable));
                }
                //else
                //{
                //    lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format3, "Subtotal Amount", subtotal1, subtotal));
                //    lstInvoice.Items.Add("");
                //}
            }lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format3, "Subtotal Amount", subtotal1, subtotal));
        }

    }


    private void getCustomerIDFirstName(out string tempp, out string idd)
    {
        string[] temp = cmbcustomerinfo.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ');
        tempp = temp[1];
        idd = temp[0];
    }

    private void getpackagepriceinfo(string date, ref double CostPerSingleAdult, ref double CostPerTwoAdults, ref byte numofdays1)
    {
        //set the information here, so we can recall the csv file into the main program.
        string[] production = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\PackagePrice.csv");
        var productQuery = from myLinesshown in production
                           let myfield1 = myLinesshown.Split(',')
                           let numofdays = byte.Parse(myfield1[0])
                           let startdateshown = myfield1[1]
                           let twinadult = myfield1[2]
                           let singlepricing = myfield1[3]
                           where startdateshown == date
                           select new
                           {
                              numofdays,
                              startdateshown,
                              twinadult,
                              singlepricing
                           };

        //setting the factor of the private function doubles and bytes to be able to get recalled, back to the top.
        foreach (var xyz in productQuery)
        {
            numofdays1 = xyz.numofdays;
            CostPerTwoAdults = double.Parse(xyz.twinadult);
            CostPerSingleAdult = double.Parse(xyz.singlepricing);
            date = xyz.startdateshown;
            break;
        }

    }
    //redo the customer information, so we can recall the string of customer id inorder to recall proper functionality. 
    private void getcustomerinfo(string customerid){
            string[] myfile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\customerinfo.csv");
             var myquery = from mylines in myfile
                      let myfield = mylines.Split(',')
                      let names = myfield[1]
                      let lastname = myfield[2]
                      let id = myfield[0]
                      where id == customerid
                      select new { id, names, lastname};}

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry to say, but this code is ugly and slow. You should be using classes for each of your tables and svoid reading large files with every click in the UI. Where's the code that should give a discount for 2 adults?

Comment: Techically, there is suppose to be no discounted code. 
The file that was given to me, states that if the "The section under C"(Array3) shows 1 person then In the packageprice.csv file you charge them a rate of D(Array 4). If the section under C shows 2 *in HolidayTrans.csv, then your coding must show Section C(array3) of pricing under Packageprice.csv then times by 2 to get the proper amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your variable names.

Refactor your code into smaller and tidier methods.

The problem becomes **MUCH** Clearer

You have a method called `getpackagepriceinfo` which takes the parameters

`(string date, ref double adult, ref double single12, ref byte numofdays1)`

where adult is `costPerSingleAdult` and single12 is `costPerTwoAdults`

When calling this method you have passed the variable `singleddigit` to the now renamed paramter `costPerTwoAdults`. What does that even mean? Did you realize you **haven't used this variable within your code**

Put code clarity first. When the code is easy to understand and working correctly, then you can start rewriting sections for speed/memory/reduced LoC/experimental language features/whatever other reason, when you do that write a comment showing the codes original intention so that when a bug gets written in to the new code you can find it quickly.

**after edit**
That's definitely an improvement. You can see now that you've got the number of adults for each transaction, but you've assigned this number into the variable used for pricing.  I think you need to refer back to the specification, which I read as "if there are 2 adults and a two adult price, then charge the twin price. Else if there is no two adult price charge 2 * single adult price, else charge the adult price" your code should read the same.

```
Decimal adultPrice
if ( twoAdults && twinPrice > 0)
    adultPrice = twinPrice;
else if ( twoAdults )
    adultPrice = 2 * singlePrice;
else
    adultPrice = singlePrice;
```

Note that this won't work if there are more than 2 adults. Not sure if that meets the specification

Comment: Will do!, Just woke up, give me a few mins to edit it so it can make some sense.

Comment: Changed it as per your request. I found the isolated problem in my calculation...but now I am having troubles finishing off the calculations x.x

Comment: My apologies, I been trying for the last hour to figure out the conceptual notion of what you stated, I figured out that I haven't used the variable (thank you for pointing it out, i didn't notice till then), but I am still having issues with finishing off the final code. Can you help verify in the points where it should be placed..sorry that I am a beginner at this :(

Comment: @user3534489 The code segment fits in immediately after the call to getPackagePriceInfo and calculates the adult price to add to your subtotal. twoAdults is a Boolean and is equal to  numAdults == 2.  Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you I figured it out! You were amazing with the help. This is the new Code that gotten

Answer (score 0):

SO the new Coding is the following. Thanks to **James Barrass** I was able to properly fix the coding to work. The problem was the following

---

```
    numberAdults = byte.Parse(Transaction.NumberofAdults);

                    if(numberAdults == 2)
                        adultpricing = AdultCost*2;
                    else
                        adultpricing = CostSingle;
```

---

Because of the following code above the entire coding is able to properly work now.

---

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] myfile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\customerinfo.csv");
        var myQuery = from mylines in myfile
                      let myfield = mylines.Split(',')
                      let CustomerID = myfield[0]
                      let CustomerFirstName = myfield[1]
                      let CustomerLastName = myfield[2]
                      orderby CustomerID, CustomerLastName, CustomerFirstName
                      select new { 
                      CustomerID, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName
                      };
        foreach (var customerinfo in myQuery) { cmbCustomer.Items.Add(customerinfo.CustomerID + " " + customerinfo.CustomerFirstName + " " + customerinfo.CustomerLastName); }

    }


    private void getCustomerFirstandID(out string customerfirst, out string idd)
    {
        string[] tempp = cmbCustomer.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ');
        customerfirst = tempp[1];
        idd = tempp[0];       
    }
    private void getCustomerInfo(string StatedID)
    {
        string[] myfile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\customerinfo.csv");
        var myQuery = from mylines in myfile
                      let myfield = mylines.Split(',')
                      let CustomerID = myfield[0]
                      let CustomerFirstName = myfield[1]
                      let CustomerLastName = myfield[2]
                      where CustomerID == StatedID
                      select new
                      {
                          CustomerID,
                          CustomerFirstName,
                          CustomerLastName
                      };


    }
    private void getPackagePriceInfo(DateTime date, ref double CostofAdults, ref double CostofSingle, ref byte NumberofDaysShown)
    {
        string[] myGivenFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\PackagePrice.csv");
        var myPackageTransaction = from myLinesGiven in myGivenFile
                                   let myFieldShown = myLinesGiven.Split(',')
                                   let NumberofDays = myFieldShown[0]
                                   let StartDate = DateTime.Parse(myFieldShown[1])
                                   let TwinAdult = myFieldShown[2]
                                   let SingleAdult = myFieldShown[3]
                                   where StartDate == date
                                   select new { 
                                   NumberofDays, StartDate, TwinAdult, SingleAdult

                                   };
        foreach (var Package in myPackageTransaction) {
            CostofSingle = double.Parse(Package.SingleAdult);
            CostofAdults = double.Parse(Package.TwinAdult);
            NumberofDaysShown = byte.Parse(Package.NumberofDays);
            date = Package.StartDate;
            break;
        }


    }

    private void cmbCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string customerfirstvariable = "";
        string iddvariable = "";
        getCustomerFirstandID(out customerfirstvariable, out iddvariable);
        getCustomerInfo(iddvariable);
        string format1 = "{0,55}{1,5}";
        string format2 = "{0,-5:d}{1,15:d}{2,20:c}{3,20:c}";
        string format3 = "{0,25}{1,19:c}{2,20:c}";
        string format4 = "{0,-15}{1,72:c}";

        string[] myGivenFile1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\holidaytrans.csv");
        var myHolidayTransaction = from myLinesGiven1 in myGivenFile1
                                   let myFieldShown = myLinesGiven1.Split(',')
                                   let CustomerGivenID = myFieldShown[0]
                                   let PackageStartDate = DateTime.Parse(myFieldShown[1])
                                   let NumberofAdults = myFieldShown[2]
                                   let NumberofKids = myFieldShown[3]
                                   where CustomerGivenID == iddvariable
                                   orderby PackageStartDate
                                   select new
                                   {
                                      CustomerGivenID, PackageStartDate, NumberofAdults, NumberofKids

                                   };
            lstInvoice.Items.Clear();
     //   foreach (var transactionfound in myHolidayTransaction) {


    //set up all variables used or to be used.
             string EndofDays = "";
            DateTime daybegin;
            DateTime startthedate;
            DateTime datebeginning = DateTime.Now;
            string idgiven = "";
            double AdultCost = 0;
            byte DaysUsed = 0;
            double adultpricing = 0;
            double KidsPricing = 0;
            double KidsCost = 3300;
            double subtotal = 0;
            double totalamt = 0;
            double subtotal1 = 0;
            double total1 = 0;
            double total = 0;
            double CostSingle = 0;
            byte numberAdults = 0;
            double adultgiven = 0;
        int xyz = 0;
            foreach (var Transaction in myHolidayTransaction)
            {
                idgiven = Transaction.CustomerGivenID;
                lstInvoice.Items.Add("Purchase Date     EndDate          Adult Price          Kid Price");
                datebeginning = Transaction.PackageStartDate;
                xyz = datebeginning.Year;
                break;

            }


            foreach (var Transaction in myHolidayTransaction)
            {
                if (Transaction.PackageStartDate.Year == xyz) {
                    getPackagePriceInfo(Transaction.PackageStartDate,ref AdultCost,  ref  CostSingle, ref DaysUsed);
                    KidsPricing = KidsCost * byte.Parse(Transaction.NumberofKids);
                    numberAdults = byte.Parse(Transaction.NumberofAdults);

                    if(numberAdults == 2)
                        adultpricing = AdultCost*2;
                    else
                        adultpricing = CostSingle;


                    subtotal += KidsPricing;
                    subtotal1 += adultpricing;
                    total += KidsPricing;
                    total1 += adultpricing;
                    daybegin = Transaction.PackageStartDate;
                    startthedate = daybegin.AddDays(DaysUsed);
                    EndofDays = startthedate.ToString("d");
                    lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format2, startthedate, EndofDays, adultpricing, KidsPricing));}
                    else
                    {
                    lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format3, "Subtotal Amount", subtotal1, subtotal));
                    lstInvoice.Items.Add(" ");
                    getPackagePriceInfo(Transaction.PackageStartDate, ref AdultCost, ref  CostSingle, ref DaysUsed);
                    KidsPricing = KidsCost * byte.Parse(Transaction.NumberofKids);
                    numberAdults = byte.Parse(Transaction.NumberofAdults);

                    if (numberAdults == 2)
                        adultpricing = AdultCost * 2;
                    else
                        adultpricing = CostSingle;
                    subtotal = KidsPricing;
                    subtotal1 = adultpricing;
                    total += KidsPricing;
                    total1 += adultpricing;
                    daybegin =Transaction.PackageStartDate;
                    startthedate = daybegin.AddDays(DaysUsed);
                    EndofDays = startthedate.ToString("d");
                    lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format2, startthedate, EndofDays, adultpricing, KidsPricing));
                    idgiven = Transaction.CustomerGivenID;
                    xyz = Transaction.PackageStartDate.Year;

             }}

   if (idgiven == "")
                {
                lstInvoice.Items.Clear();
                lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format1, "Sorry no Transaction Found For" + " ", customerfirstvariable));
                } 
   else
                lstInvoice.Items.Add(" "); 
                lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format3, "Subtotal Amount", subtotal1, subtotal));
                lstInvoice.Items.Add(" ");
                lstInvoice.Items.Add(string.Format(format3, "Total Amount", total1, total));

        } 
                }



            }
```